# Strange error while parsing string type Date value from 'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss' to 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss' in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am currently trying to parse a string type date value from formatted as  'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss' to 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'. The following code works perfectly.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string tranDate = "18/02/2019 11:02:30";
        DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(tranDate, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString());
    }
}
```

**Output: 2/18/2019 11:02:30 AM**

But when I changed the value of tranDate as :

```
string tranDate = "18/02/2019 13:02:30";
```

I am getting strange error as:

```
Run-time exception (line -1): String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Stack Trace:

[System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.]
   at System.DateTimeParse.ParseExact(String s, String format, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles style)
   at System.DateTime.ParseExact(String s, String format, IFormatProvider provider)
   at Program.Main()
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Use `HH` instead of `hh`, e.g. use `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss` as DateTime-Format. With `HH` `DateTime.ParseExact` expects a 24 hour format, in which 13 is valid, with `hh` (12 hour format) it is not.

Comment: @TobiasTengler It is working now. Thanks

Comment: Also, the `DateTime` struct have a couple of `ToString()` overloads. The one you've chosen will return a string representation of the `DateTime`'s value based on the current culture. If you want a specific one, better provide a format to the `ToString()` method as well: `Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString( "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));`